# Javascript check surrounding text

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am in the process of writing a BBCode style editor - I have excellent reasons for doing this rather than using an off-the-shelf effort. I have got most of it working correctly but I need to test for one condition.  Consider the following markup

```
[para=2]
abc
[/para]
[para=0]
123
[/pa|ra]
```

The pipe character above is not a typo as you will see in a moment - I am using it as a placeholder.

Now imagine that the next user action is to insert - my version of - the bold markdown tag [bold][/bold].  My code can handle doing this whether or not the user has already selected some of the existing text - e.g. abc.

However, look at the following situations

1. abc selected - the transformation yields [bold]abc[/bold]
2. caret after the c of abc - the transformation yields abc[bold][/bold]
3. The caret at the pipe, |, charcter  in the last [/para]

At present my code merrily obliges and returns [pa|[bold][/bold]ra].

Clearly, what I need to do is to establish that the user's selection, or current caret position does not sit entirely within one of my markdown tags (I already have code that checks that the selection does not overlap a markdown tag.

I would need to do something along the lines of "looking around" the selection start & end positions to detect that the location is inside a markdown tag.

Perhaps the solution - as the word lookaround suggests - is in a RegEx.  However, my regex skills are pretty basic so I would much appreciate any help.

Comment: By that time, have you checked that your markup is valid? In that case, it would be enough to check whether there is a `]` following before the next `[`.

Comment: I ended up doing what you suggest

Comment: I'll make it an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know your markup is valid, then you can find out if a position is inside a tag, if there is a `]` before the next `[`. You can probably simply amend your pattern with the following lookahead to rule out these cases:

```
(?![^\[]*\])...
```

Or if you don't like escaping, this would actually work just fine:

```
(?![^[]*])...
```

But in this case, the readability is somewhat questionable.

Comment: Sorry - not sure why I never got around to accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [caret plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/caret/) split text text in the position of the cursor and use two regular expressions to test if the cursor is inside a tag:

```
var editor = $('.editor');
var pos = editor.caret();
var text = editor.val()
var before = text.substring(0, pos);
var after = text.substring(pos, text.length);
if (before.match(/\[[^\[]*$/) && after.match(/^[^\[]*\]/)) {
    alert('inside');
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The caret plugin is not required really.  The textarea.textRange object provides all the information required.  Perhaps it is not cross browser but who cares - I only need it to work in Chrome.